# Force variable to have a particular memory .noinit location on PSOC5

Tags: gcc, memory, linker, psoc

Is there a way to make sure that a variable in a NOLOAD memory section is given a specific location in memory?

Do I need to edit the linker script, or is there a linker command to do this?